# Show nested dropdown with overflow hidden set to parent dropdown

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, overflow

I have a dropdown menu nested in a parent dropdown. The parent dropdown is set to overflow: hidden, and I use max-height to animate the height transition. So it must have overflow: hidden for that animation to work properly. The problem is now I have a child dropdown nested in that parent dropdown. Becuase the parent dropdown is overflow: hidden, so the child dropdown is hide by the parent dropdown.
My question is: Is there a way to animate the height of the parent dropdown and also show the child dropdown? I do not want to animate the opacity. I think for max-height to animate, we must set the dropdown to overflow: hidden, but this will hide all the child dropdown. Maybe there is another way?

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="nav-item">
        Nav Item
        <ul class="dropdown">   
          <li>  <a href="">LINK</a></li>
          <li>  
            <a href="">LINK</a>
            <ul class="inner-dropdown">
              <li><a href="">link</a></li>
              <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            </ul>  
            </li>
          <li>  <a href="">LINK</a></li>
        <ul/>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-item{
   width:100%
   height:20px;
   background:#56bcf9;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 30px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-item:hover .dropdown{
  max-height: 500px;
}
.dropdown{
    width:500px;
    background:#666;
    position:absolute;
    max-height: 0; 
    transition: max-height .5s ease-in; 
  overflow: hidden;
    
}

.dropdown li {
  padding: 15px;
}

.inner-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  background: pink;
  width: 200px;
  top: 60px;
  left: 540px;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-item{
   width:100%
   height:20px;
   background:#56bcf9;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 30px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-item:hover .dropdown{
  max-height: 500px;
}
.dropdown{
    width:500px;
    background:#666;
    position:absolute;
    max-height: 0; 
    transition: max-height .5s ease-in; 
  overflow: hidden;
    
}

.dropdown li {
  padding: 15px;
}

.inner-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  background: pink;
  width: 200px;
  top: 60px;
  left: 540px;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <div class="nav-item">
        Nav Item
        <ul class="dropdown">   
          <li>  <a href="">LINK</a></li>
          <li>  
            <a href="">LINK</a>
            <ul class="inner-dropdown">
              <li><a href="">link</a></li>
              <li><a href="">link</a></li>
            </ul>  
            </li>
          <li>  <a href="">LINK</a></li>
        <ul/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting `overflow: visible;` In the `dropdown` class, the menu is set by giving the animation under the `inner-dropdown` menu.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-item{
  max-width:500px;
  background:#56bcf9;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding:30px 0;
}
.nav-item:hover .dropdown{
  visibility:visible;
  max-height: 1000px;
}


.dropdown{
    width:500px;
    background:#666;
    position:absolute;
    max-height: 0px; 
    transition: all .5s ease-in; 
    overflow: visible;
    top:60px;
    padding:0;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.dropdown li {
  padding: 15px 0;
  color:white;
}
.dropdown li:hover .inner-dropdown{
 max-height:500px;
}
.dropdown li:hover .inner-dropdown li{
  opacity: 1; 
}
.inner-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  top: 80px;
  left: 500px;
  max-height:0;
   padding:0;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out; 
}
.inner-dropdown li {
   opacity: 0; 
   transition: all .5s ease-in-out; 
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="nav-item">
    Nav Item
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li> <a href="">LINK</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="">LINK</a>
        <ul class="inner-dropdown">
          <li><a href="">link</a></li>
          <li><a href="">link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="">LINK</a></li>
      <ul/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does show the child dropdown, but the parent dropdown now visible, I also need to make the parent dropdown hide when not hover.

Comment: I apologize. I did not realize that it must be hidden. I just modified the code. It works now.

Comment: no problem! Thank you for your try. I think it's almost there! The only thing is the parent dropdown's link text will show before the dropdown expands to full height, which looks a little bit weird. My only thinking is to set the overflow hidden to the parent dropdown so the the link and dropdown will animate at the same time. But that will cause the inner dropdown hidden by the parent. I think that's the key of my problem.